# How does flex match the beginning of line anchor?

Tags: regex, algorithm, flex-lexer, finite-automata, nfa

I've always wondered how the beginning of input anchor (`^`) was converted to a FSA in flex. I know that the end of line anchor (`$`) is matched by the expression `r/\n` where `r` is the expression to match. How's the beginning of input anchor matched? The only solution I see is to use start conditions. How can it be implemented in a program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

End of line marker `$` is different from `\n` in that it matches `EOF` as well, even if the end-of-line marker `\n` or `\r\n` is not found at the end of the file.

I did not look at flex's implementation, but I would implement both `^` and `$` using boolean flags. The `^` flag would be initially set, then reset to `false` after the first character in a line, then set back to `true` after the next end-of-line marker, and so on.

Comment: Thus your way of implementing it would be similar to start conditions right?

Comment: @AaditMShah I am not sure what you mean by "start conditions". I edited the answer to fix typos and missing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If your scanner uses the ^anchor, then every start-condition needs two initial-state entries:

- Beginning-of-line, and
- otherwise.

Flex does this, and peeks behind the input pointer to determine which entry to consult.

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of line anchor is matched by the pattern:

beginningOfLine    ^.

(a caret followed by a point)

Example (numbering lines of a text):

```
%{
int ln = 1;
%}

beginningOfLine ^.
newline \n

%%
{beginningOfLine} { if (ln == 1) {
                        printf ("%d \t", ln);
                        printf (yytext);
                        ln++; 
                    }else{
                        printf (yytext);
                    }
                  }

{newline}         { printf ("\n");
                    printf ("%d \t", ln);
                    ln++; }


%%
```